# Looping through excel sheets - array index out of range

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel with 17 sheets and I am running a loop to extract the data from all the sheets but the first one. All the sheets are identically structured, yet something wrong happens when my i = 6 as I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-244-ea6f45e973a4> in <module>()
      4     df_1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\filippo.sebastio\OneDrive - ELEVATE\Target\Target Download 28 Feb\Quantitative data\SCHAEFER_Putian ZhangSheng\zhangsheng  --   RSAP Factory Metrics Tool- Hardcopy Form draft to publish 2018 12.xlsx', i , header = 4, index_col=1)
      5     worksheet_1 = workbook.sheet_by_index(i)
----> 6     month = worksheet_1.cell(5,4).value
      7     df_1 = df_1.drop(df_1.index[0])
      8     df_1 = df_1.drop(df_1.index[-1])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py in cell(self, rowx, colx)
    406             xfx = None
    407         return Cell(
--> 408             self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
    409             self._cell_values[rowx][colx],
    410             xfx,

IndexError: array index out of range
```

This is my loop

```
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for i in range(1,17):
    df_1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\filippo.sebastio\OneDrive - ELEVATE\Target\Target Download 28 Feb\Quantitative data\SCHAEFER_Putian ZhangSheng\zhangsheng  --   RSAP Factory Metrics Tool- Hardcopy Form draft to publish 2018 12.xlsx', i , header = 4, index_col=1)
    worksheet_1 = workbook.sheet_by_index(i)
    month = worksheet_1.cell(5,4).value 
    df_1 = df_1.drop(df_1.index[0])
    df_1 = df_1.drop(df_1.index[-1])
    df_1 = df_1.drop(df_1.columns[0], axis=1)
    df_1 = df_1.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
    for col in  df_1.columns[0:3]:
        df_1[col] = pd.to_numeric(df_1[col], errors='coerce')
    df_1['mean'] = df_1.iloc[:, 0:3].mean(axis=1)
    df_1 = df_1[[ 'mean']]
    df_1_t = df_1.T
    df_1_t['Month'] = month
    df_1_t['Factory'] = worksheet_1.cell(3,2).value
    df_1_t['Factory_id'] = worksheet_0.cell(3,2 ).value
    df_1_t['Country'] = worksheet_0.cell(4,2 ).value
    df_1_t['Consultant'] = worksheet_0.cell(5,2 ).value
    list_.append(df_1_t)

list_    
frame = pd.concat(list_)

frame
```

I checked and the particular cell in the sheet is not empty (all the sheets are the same and similarly populated). Also, the loop works fine throughout all the other sheets - (1 to 5 and 7 to 17). What could be the problem?

Comment: Is there a hidden sheet? Can you try unhiding sheets and see if the 6th sheet is structured differently?

Comment: I unhid the sheet and a drop down reference sheet came up. I moved the reference sheet to the last sheet, yet, I re-run the loop and I have always the same problem.

Comment: Is it still failing at i=6 or when i=17?

Comment: always at i = 6

Comment: you can put the code in the for loop in a try / except, so that it will run for all the valid sheets, and skip the ones that fail

Comment: Thanks, I am quite new with Python, can you show me how or point me to some reference?

Comment: Also, interesting bit, I moved my problematic sheet (i=6) to the end and yet, the problem keeps on happening in the same position..so, it is not related to the sheet apparently

Comment: Replace `month = worksheet_1.cell(5, 4).value` to `month = worksheet_1.cell(5, 4)`

Comment: I removed .value, but it still gives me the exact same problem as in my initial message..

Comment: First row or column is 0 not 1. Are you sure following this. `(5,4) is E6`.

Comment: just to validate your sheet, have you renamed you sheet 6  to 1 and 1 to 6 and check if always sheet 6 is out?

Comment: Rename does not change much - the problem is in that sheet and caused by the command worksheet_1.cell().value - if I remove the comment, the loop works great

Comment: SO, I just figured that if I change my ceode from worksheet_1.cell(5,4).value to worksheet_1.cell(1,1) in all the different sheets it will return the value of 1,1 of the excel file, but in sheet number 6, where it returns the value of 4,2. It is just like this sheet is misaligned with the rest!